# type 'set''s difference between __str__ and printing directly

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, python-2.x

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.version_info
Out[2]: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

In [3]: b=set([10,20,40,32,67,40,20,89,300,400,15])

In [4]: b
Out[4]: {10, 11, 15, 20, 32, 40, 67, 89, 111, 300, 400}
```

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.version_info
Out[2]: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

In [3]: b=set([10,20,40,32,67,40,20,89,300,400,15])

In [4]: b
Out[4]: set([32, 67, 40, 10, 11, 300, 15, 400, 20, 89, 111])
```

why have this different between 2 and 3?

Answer (score 4):

Because the `{...}` syntax [wasn't introduced until Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features), and by that time the `set([...])` `repr()` format was already established.

So to keep existing Python 2 code that may have relied on the `set([...])` representation working, the `repr()` wasn't changed in the 2.x series. Python 3 had `{...}` notation for sets from the start.